# Definiton of a certain symbol in a proof(The right linear languages are exactly the finite state languages)

Tags: finite-automata, formal-grammars

**I want to stress that i am not looking for a proof of this question, but rather if someone(that is familiar with the proof and it's context) can explain to me what the symbol 'e' means in the context.**

[image: brief instructions of proof]

the letter 'e' first appears in line 6:S $\rightarrow $e...

This is crucial for me, because i am not able to deduct from the context what its meaning and write a formal proof

Answer (score 2):

The letter $e$ stands the empty word, which is usually denoted by the symbol $\varepsilon$.
A hint of this is that, according to step 6, if $S \to e$ then the initial state $S$ is also a final state.